# How to direct the flow of variables between modules in R Shiny ui and server functions?

Tags: r, shiny, module

I'm trying to understand the flow of reactive variables through different modules. This is so I can house certain types of calculations in one module, and another type of calculation in another module for the purpose of code/function clarity. In the simple example code shown below, in **BASE APP** the user input `input$svc` and starting data frame `df` are sent to **MODULE 1** where each `df` cell is multiplied by the value in `input$svc` and is returned to BASE APP as the second table rendered by code `allocTbl_ui("tblModule")` in BASE APP (encoded in object `upd_dat`) .  From BASE APP these second table products are then sent to **MODULE 2** for adding a value of 10 to each cell and is returned to the BASE APP as the third table rendered by code `mod_2_ui('mod2')` in BASE APP (encoded in object `upd_dat2`).

To better understand the flow of variables between modules, I'd like to change this so `upd_dat2` instead flows back to MODULE 1 and the second table rendered reflects a `cbind()` of `up_dat` and `up_dat2` (column headers modified for `up_data2` of course to avoid header dupes; something like `A_10`, `B_10`, `C_10` for example), with no 3rd table rendered. How can this be done?

Basically I want `up_data2` to flow to MODULE 1 instead of back to BASE APP, if this possible.

Code:

```
# BASE APP

library(shiny)
library(DT)

source("C:/Users/laran/OneDrive/Desktop/Temp/Module1.R")

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    DTOutput("table"),
    sliderInput("svc", '', min = 0, max = 10, value = 1),
    allocTbl_ui("tblModule"), 
    mod_2_ui('mod2') # add second module
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  df <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = 4:6, C = 7:9)
  
  output$table <- renderDT({datatable(df)})
  
  # store returned value from first module
  upd_dat <- allocTbl_server("tblModule",
                             df = reactive(df),
                             svc = reactive(input$svc))
  
  # send this returned value to second module
  mod_2_server('mod2', upd_dat)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

# MODULE 1

source("C:/Users/laran/OneDrive/Desktop/Temp/Module2.R")

library(DT)
# first module
allocTbl_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DTOutput(ns("tbl"))
}
# first module server    
allocTbl_server <- function(id, df, svc) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    # store updated data as a reactive
    new_dat <- reactive({
      df() * as.numeric(svc())
    })
    output$tbl <- renderDT({
      datatable(new_dat())
    })
    # return updated data
    return(new_dat)
  })
}

# MODULE 2

mod_2_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  DTOutput(ns('tbl2'))
}
# adds 10 to df and shows as DT
mod_2_server <- function(id, upd_dat2){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    output$tbl2 <- renderDT({
      data <- upd_dat2() + 10
      datatable(data)
    })
  })
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Shiny `server`, you can input the output of one module into another module, even though the module server is initialised in a later line.

```
# BASE APP

library(shiny)
library(DT)

# MODULE 1

library(DT)
# first module
allocTbl_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  DTOutput(ns("tbl"))
}
# first module server    
allocTbl_server <- function(id, df, svc, upd_dat_2) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    # store updated data as a reactive
    new_dat <- reactive({
      df() * as.numeric(svc())
    })
    output$tbl <- renderDT({
      upd_dat_2_clean <- upd_dat_2()
      colnames(upd_dat_2_clean) <- paste0(colnames(upd_dat_2_clean), "_10")
      table_data <- cbind(new_dat(), upd_dat_2_clean)
      datatable(table_data)
    })
    # return updated data
    return(new_dat)
  })
}

# MODULE 2

# adds 10 to df
mod_2_server <- function(id, upd_dat2){
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session){
    
    upd_dat_2 <- reactive({
      upd_dat2() + 10
    })
    
    return(upd_dat_2)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  mainPanel(
    DTOutput("table"),
    sliderInput("svc", '', min = 0, max = 10, value = 1),
    allocTbl_ui("tblModule")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  df <- data.frame(A = 1:3, B = 4:6, C = 7:9)
  
  output$table <- renderDT({datatable(df)})
  
  # store returned value from first module
  upd_dat <- allocTbl_server("tblModule",
                             df = reactive(df),
                             svc = reactive(input$svc),
                             upd_dat_2 = upd_dat_2)
  
  # send this returned value to second module
  upd_dat_2 <- mod_2_server('mod2', upd_dat)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: That works. With the objective of code clarity when segregating similar processing functions into separate files and with reactive variables passed between files, which is your preference: (a) full module with namespaces like in this example or (b) a simple function that is likewise compartmentalized into a separate file and otherwise does the same thing? Let's also assume the calculations under consideration are only used once when running the code (in other words, there are no other places in the code where that  module or function is deployed).

Comment: In this case, I'd probably go with b as this gets the job done and is not too complex.